# How can I replace characters in a string in Python, but not using string methods?

Tags: python, string, replace, character

I just started learning Python, and I'm stuck in this problem: I have a DNA sequence, and I need to return its complementary sequence. For example, if I have `ATTGCA`, it should return `TAACGT`. This is, replace `A` by `T`, `T` by `A`, `C` by `G` and `G` by `C`. It's an exercise, and I'm not supposed to use string methods. Everything I tried until now, return me 'T' as answer. Seems it only recognize the first letter, then stops. How can I do it?

I tried:

```
>>> def get_complementary_sequence(dna):
    for char in dna:
        if char == 'A':
            return 'T'
        elif char == 'T':
            return 'A'
        elif char == 'C':
            return 'G'
        elif char == 'G':
            return 'C'


>>> get_complementary_sequence('ATTGCA')
'T'
```

And also tried:

```
def get_complementary_sequence(dna):
    sequence = ""
    for nucleotide in dna:
        if nucleotide == 'A':
            return sequence + 'T'
        elif nucleotide == 'T':
            return sequence + 'A'
        elif nucleotide == 'C':
            return sequence + 'G'
        elif nucleotide == 'G':
            return sequence + 'C'
        return sequence


>>> get_complementary_sequence('ATTGCA')
'T'
```

Comment: `Everything I tried until now` -> then show us what you tried?

Comment: >>> def get_complementary_sequence(dna):
 for char in dna:
  if char == 'A':
   return 'T'
  elif char == 'T':
   return 'A'
  elif char == 'C':
   return 'G'
  elif char == 'G':
   return 'C'

  
>>> get_complementary_sequence('ATTGCA')
'T'
>>>

Comment: Post this code in your question.. Edit your question.

Comment: Question edited with the codes!

Answer (score 5):

try a dictionary, that way you'll also don't need the `if`'s and `elif`'s:

```
In [45]: dic={'A':'T','T':'A','C':'G','G':'C'}

In [46]: strs="ATTGCA"

In [47]: ''.join(dic[x] for x in strs)
Out[47]: 'TAACGT'
```

or using `map()`:

```
In [52]: ''.join(map(dic.get,strs))
Out[52]: 'TAACGT'
```

Comment: `join` is a "string method", so I wonder if this meets the requirements. Though I suppose one could argue that even `+` is a string method (`__add__`).

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves IMHO the string method he's concerned with is `replace()`.

Comment: Maybe. He said "I'm not supposed to use string methods" not "I'm not supposed to use replace()".

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I would have been more concerned about his using `"ATAGGTCTCTTA".translate({65: 84, 67: 71, 84: 65, 71: 67})`. `replace()` would have been difficult to use because of the symmetric replacements...

Comment: @TimPietzcker I never knew about this method ,thanks for that. But this only works in py3k I guess?

Comment: Yes, in Python 2, there's `string.maketrans("ATCG", "TAGC")` whose result you can then pass to `"ATAAGCCGTA".translate()`.

Answer (score 3):

A string is also a sequence of characters, so you can iterate through it:

```
for char in sequence:
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an equivalent of Ashwini Chaudhary's elegant solution which maybe more comprehensible for beginners:

```
complements = {'A': 'T',
               'T': 'A',
               'C': 'G',
               'G': 'C'}
dna_sequence = 'ATTGCA'
new_sequence = []
for char in dna_sequence:
    new_sequence.append(complements[char])
# new_sequence is now ['T', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T']
result = ''.join(new_sequence) # result in 'TAACGT'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using dictionaries, entirely without string methods :)

```
trans = {'A':'T','T':'A','C':'G','G':'C'}
with open("temp.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for character in mystring:
        outfile.write(trans[character])
with open("temp.txt") as infile:
    result = infile.read()
```

Comment: +1 why doesn't this came to my mind :), but you can reduce your solution to [this](http://pastebin.com/m5wB2jJW)

Comment: Neat. You might like to use Python [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html)

Answer (score 1):

This solution is easy to understand. Hope it helps.

```
def get_complement(nucleotide):
    """ (str) ->str
    """

    sequence = ""
    for char in nucleotide:
        if char == "A":
            sequence = sequence + "T"
        if char == "T":
            sequence = sequence + "A"
        if char == "G":
            sequence = sequence + "C"
        if char == "C":
            sequence = sequence + "G"

    return sequence
```